# How to add up the numbers 1 through "n" and print out the result?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, while-loop

I have written the following code for an exercise I was given, nonetheless, when I try to submit it,  I get an incorrect answer for my code.

So this is my code:

```
def problem(n):
    my_sum = 0
    while my_sum < n: 
        my_sum = n 
        my_sum = my_sum + n 
    print (my_sum)
```

**What they have asked me to code is the following:** Write a function problem(n): that adds up the numbers 1 through n and
prints out the result.  You should use either a 'while' loop or a 'for' loop.
Be sure that you check your answer on several numbers n.

Comment: this is wrong because you aren't adding all the numbers. you shouldnt be iterating over my_sum but over 1..n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def problem(n):

   print sum(xrange(1, n+1))
```

If you are not allowed to use the built in sum function, you can try this:

```
def problem(n):

   counter = 0
   for i in range(1, n+1):
       counter += i

   print counter
```

The top example uses a for loop in what is called list comprehension, which is a shorter way of utilizing the regular for loop.

Comment: it has to be a while or for loop though

Comment: Get rid of the braces, you do not need them. In fact, it makes it slower (constructing a possible huge list instead of using a generator to get one value at a time).

Comment: BTW, you can do that 1st version more efficiently: `sum(range(1,n+1))`

Comment: If this is py2 then surely `sum(xrange(1, n+1))` - no?

Comment: @AChampion I just did some `timeit` tests and you're correct: `xrange` is at least 10% faster, even for small `n`.

Comment: @AChampion: FWIW, here's [my `timeit` code](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/ea746db64ecd17c2fb5d6907342f9911)

Comment: Why not `sum(xrange(n+1))`?

Comment: One extra calculation, and not strictly the same as original ask `sum 1 to n`.

Comment: Please see my recent edit.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Interestingly, `sum(xrange(n+1))` might be slightly faster since it doesn't need to pass the `1` arg. But it's hard to tell with my `timeit` code, since the difference is smaller than the variation in times between runs.

Comment: @MaxNoe There are surprisingly many cases in which constructing an intermediate list comprehension is quicker than using a generator (since most Python implementations heavily optimize list comprehensions). Don't know whether that's true here, just a cool tidbit.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will iterate through the `while` loop only once and when `my_sum` becomes `>=` to `n` it will stop.

What you need is:

```
for x in range(1, n+1):                      
    my_sum += x
```

This will do the job. `n+1` is done because the right boundary of `range()` is non-inclusive.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!